# How to change Mediapipe CameraInput zoom. Are its parameters width and height flipped?

Tags: android-studio, mediapipe

When using Mediapipe library for image processing, I can choose camera as input. However, the camera input has very poor resolution and it is zoomed in. I wanted to change the zoom and resolution, so I looked into the source code to find out how the resolution was set. The code path is the following:

In `CameraInput` class, you start the camera by calling

```
public void start(Activity activity, EGLContext eglContext, CameraFacing cameraFacing, int width, int height) {
    ...

    if (width != 0 && height != 0) {
        this.updateOutputSize(width, height);
    }
    ...
```

Then

```
public void updateOutputSize(int width, int height) {
    Size displaySize = this.cameraHelper.computeDisplaySizeFromViewSize(new Size(width, height));
    ...
```

which goes to `CameraXPreviewHelper` class

```
public Size computeDisplaySizeFromViewSize(Size viewSize) {
    return this.frameSize;
}
```

and the place where `frameSize` is set is in function

```
private void startCamera(Context context, LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner, CameraHelper.CameraFacing cameraFacing, @Nullable SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, @Nullable Size targetSize) {
    ...
    targetSize = this.getOptimalViewSize(targetSize);
    if (targetSize == null) {
        targetSize = TARGET_SIZE;
    }

    Size rotatedSize = new Size(targetSize.getHeight(), targetSize.getWidth());

    ...

    this.preview = (new Preview.Builder()).setTargetResolution(rotatedSize).build();
    ...
    this.preview.setSurfaceProvider(this.renderExecutor, (request) -> {
        this.frameSize = request.getResolution();
    ...
```

I don't completely understand the relationship between `this.preview` and `request`, but since one setting the resolution and the other getting the resolution makes me think they share the same resolution. But the problem is the resolution is rotated.

So when I try flip the width and height when calling `CamaraInput::start(...)` function, I got a high (very close to my provided resolution) resolution and zoomed out result.

My question:

1. is there a easy way to choose a specific resolution?
2. is the source code wrong that the parameters width and height are flipped?